# Cast ImageView versus using the new operator in java (Android)

Tags: android

I have tried to find the answer to this, but have been unsuccesful so far. I guess the answer lies in the basic object oriented mindset.

Basically, I have this code which works fine:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    ImageView button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DaImageView);
    button.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Test output.");
    return false;
}

}
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:src="@drawable/spinning_wheel2"
    android:id="@+id/DaImageView"
    android:longClickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, what I want to do is something like:

```
button = new ImageView(this);
button.setId(R.id.DaImageView);
button.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

where line 2 should be referring to the right view. When it is done like this, the onTouchListener does not respond. What is the reason for this?

The reason I want to do it like this is because I have a custom class extending ImageView, hence it cannot be cast like this:

```
button = (customClass) findViewById(R.id.DaImageView);
```

I appreciate any comments you may have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a [custom component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) you have to specify the class name in the XML layout in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<yourpackage.CustomClassName
    android:id="@+id/DaImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:src="@drawable/spinning_wheel2"
    android:longClickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So you can cast - now without problems - in you code:

```
CustomClass cc = (CustomClass)findViewById(R.id.DaImageView);
```

If you create a new instance of you `CustomClass`, you need to add manually this view into the layout - by code - that is different than retrieve the existing instance defined in the XML layout file!

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! The devil is in the details, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setContentView()` with a supplied XML resource, the XML layout file is 'inflated' such that the XML file is used to generate a hierarchy of real View objects (consisting of a parent `LinearLayout` with a child `ImageView`; both of which are `View`s).

Instead of using the XML file, you could have created this hierarchy of objects programmatically: That is, make a `new` instance of `LinearLayout`, set that as the content view for your `Activity`, then make a `new` instance of `ImageView` and add that as a child to the `LinearLayout`.

When you do this (quoting your code):

```
button = new ImageView(this);
button.setId(R.id.DaImageView);
```

You are creating a new `ImageView`, as opposed to grabbing a reference to one that has already been inflated from the XML resource. To have that `View` object actually appear in the hierarchy, you could `add` it to the parent `LinearLayout`.

And, this is perfectly correct:

```
button = (customClass) findViewById(R.id.DaImageView);
```

If you have an object of type of your custom `View` then it's correct to cast the result of `findViewById()` as you have done.

So in summary, from reading your question I think the two main points for you to understand are:

1. You *can* use `findViewById()` to grab a reference to a custom extended `View`. Cast it if you need to access properties of your extended `View`. You can use `findViewById()` whether the `View` hierarchy structure was created programmatically, inflated from XML or a mixture of both. Once the hierarchy exists, it makes no difference whether it came from XML or program.
2. If you programmatically create a `View`, you need to add it to the parent `View` that is set as the layout manager for your `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The quick fix is what kryst4l answered. However, I will probably have to do it in this way in a later stage. Cheers!